# html form to submit to express route with parameters

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have a form that takes an input. On submit of the form it directs the user to `/images?s1="whatever the user inputs"`

In express, I have two routes. One for `/images` and another for `/images/:s1`. The problem is.. the form submits back to the `/images` route in express. I want the form to submit to `/images/:s1` so I can use the URL params. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

```
<form action="/images" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="s1">
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `/images/:s1` is not images?something, the `s1` in this case is a route param. like this: `images/1`.  A route query will always be redirected to de same route.   Consider using another route

Comment: thank you. That makes more sense.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If just using only HTML then no, you can not do that.

You can achieve this by using a javascript function like this

HTML:

```
<form method="GET" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" id="myInput">
        <input type="button" onclick="mySubmitFunction()" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function mySubmitFunction() {
           var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");     // Get form element
           var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");   // Get input element
           var inputValue = myInput.value;                     // Get input value
           myForm.action = "image/" + inputValue + "";         // Action path
           window.location = myForm.action;                    // Remove trailing question mark
           myForm.submit();                                    // Submit the form
    }
</script>
```

Note: This is not a solution, It's a work around

Edit: this is the result

[image]

Hope this would help